# Nvim: $VIRTUAL_ENV exists but appears to be inactive. This could lead to unexpected results

Tags: python, vim, neovim, pyenv, coc.nvim

Using nvim and pyenv for my virtual environments. When I run `:checkhealth` I'm shown the following info for my Python 3 provider:

```
## Python 3 provider (optional)
- INFO: pyenv: Path: /Users/bioround/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv
- INFO: pyenv: $PYENV_ROOT is not set. Infer from `pyenv root`.
- INFO: pyenv: Root: /Users/bioround/.pyenv
- INFO: Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/Users/bioround/.pyenv/versions/nvim3/bin/python"
- WARNING: $VIRTUAL_ENV exists but appears to be inactive. This could lead to unexpected results.
  - ADVICE:
    - If you are using Zsh, see: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7654
- INFO: Executable: /Users/bioround/.pyenv/versions/nvim3/bin/python
- INFO: Python version: 3.6.0
- INFO: pynvim version: 0.4.1
- OK: Latest pynvim is installed.
```

Per the advice message, I've visited http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7654 and followed the steps there - I created a `.zshenv` file and added the lines shown. However, the warning message persists.

Comment: Try moving the lines you added to `.zshenv` to `.zshrc`. Adding those lines to `.zshenv` instead of `.zshrc` is not always necessary.

Comment: Just tried this and it still doesn't seem to fix the problem after sourcing `.zshrc`